# How to get image name from image URl using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I need to display image name in a text field. I got the image url but I am not able to get the image name.

```
function onSavedDocURISuccesss(imageURI) {
    storeFileURI = imageURI;
    WL.Logger.info("storeFileURI  " + storeFileURI + "  showURIId   "
            + showURIId + "    "
            + storeFileURI.substr(storeFileURI.lastIndexOf('/')))
    if (storeFileURI == null || storeFileURI == undefined)
        storeFileURI = "unsupported file"

    $("#" + showURIId).val(storeFileURI)
}
```

Comment: What's the content of `storeFileURI`?

Comment: Please share your complete code in JSFiddle or Full StackOverflow code demo.

Comment: @fracz - look at the 2nd line of the code-snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a substring of the full path like this:

```js
var fp = "path/to/img.jpg"
$(function(){
  $("#result").text(fp.substring(fp.lastIndexOf("/")+1,fp.length));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this using split and then taking the last value.

```
function onSavedDocURISuccesss(imageURI) {
  storeFileURI = imageURI.split('/');
  $("#" + showURIId).val(storeFileURI[storeFileURI.length-1]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const image_uri = 'https://stackoverflow.com/images/sample.png'
const image_name = image_uri.split('/').pop()
/* alternative method 
 const image_name = image_uri.split('/').reverse()[0]
*/

console.log(image_name)
```